# Which song plays while Hughes and Mustang talk during episode 30 of FMA:B?

Tags: music, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

In episode 30 of *Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood*, the song starts playing 12 minutes in while Hughes and Mustang were talking. It sounds like *Requiem for the Brigadier General*, except it's a soft piano.

Is it a different version of the same song? If so, I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1):

It's ***Happiness ~Requiem from The Blind Alchemist~*** by Akira Senju, the 28th track from the album *Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood Original Soundtrack 1*.